Variation on the ballot problem
Suppose there is an election between Alice and Bob. Alice gets $A$ votes, and Bob gets $B < A$ votes. Votes are counted sequentially, with all orders equally likely. Let $X_n =$ (# votes cast for Alice) $-$ (# votes cast for Bob) when $n$ votes have been counted.
I’m interested in values (or estimates) of the following quantities in terms of $A$ and $B$:

What is the distribution and expectation of $\max_n X_n$? That is, what is the max size of Alice’s lead over Bob?

What is the distribution and expectation of $\max_n (-X_n\vee 0)$? That is, what is the max size of Bob’s lead over Alice (if there ever is one).


It doesn’t seem like it should be too hard to estimate these quantities, but I’m not seeing a way in. I’m interested in what techniques would be used for this kind of problem.

When $~n~$ votes have been counted, the exact probability that $~k~$ of those votes were cast for Alice is $$\frac{\binom{A}{k} ~\binom{B}{n-k}}{\binom{A+B}{n}}.$$  You might be regarding this as irrelevant, if you are only interested in obtaining estimated answers, based on the assumption that $~A, ~B, ~$ and $~n~$ are large.
